# How can i resolve this memory leak?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, nsstring, analyzer, alloc

this is my snippet:

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andConfig:(PGParams*) params 
{

 for (int i=0; i<[conf.map count]; i++) 
  [conf.map replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:
      [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@&sito=%@", 
       [conf.map objectAtIndex:i], [params sito]]];

 for (int i=0; i<[conf.orto count]; i++) 
   [conf.orto replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:
      [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@&sito=%@", 
       [conf.orto objectAtIndex:i], [params sito]]];

 for (int i=0; i<[conf.mix count]; i++) 
    [conf.mix replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:
      [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@&sito=%@", 
       [conf.mix objectAtIndex:i], [params sito]]];

}
```

Compiling this code with `RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER` option (*Property->Build Options->Run Static Analyzer*), it show me a leak on `[[NSString alloc] ...`.

> RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER
> Activating this setting will cause Xcode to run the Clang static analysis tool on qualifying source files.  This tool presently supports C and Objective-C files. [RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER]

How can i resolve it?

thanks in advance,
allberto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right.  You're allocating an object that you own (because you invoked `+alloc`), but then you're never releasing it.

You can replace all instances of `[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:...]` with `[NSString stringWithFormat:...]` to fix the leak.